# Using an IFrame API in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Doing the following:

```
    let doc = this.iframe.contentDocument || this.iframe.contentWindow;
    let content = `...`
    doc!.open();
    doc!.write(content);
    doc!.close();
```

However the Typescript linter says:

> Property 'write' does not exist on type 'Document | Window'.
> Property 'write' does not exist on type 'Window'.ts(2339)

How do we fix that?

Comment: typecase doc to `any`.  `let doc = (this.iframe.contentDocument || this.iframe.contentWindow) as any;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because according to TS DOM typings, `write` only exists on `Document` type.
Maybe it worth updating TS version, maybe not)

There is one fast workaround:

```js
let doc = (this.iframe.contentDocument || this.iframe.contentWindow) as Document;
```

Please, double check if `write` method exists in case `this.iframe.contentDocument === null // true`